# Ubuntu Linux -- JVM has stopped

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0c7e9fb100, pid=10645, tid=139691734513408
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_40-b43) (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.0-b56 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libxcb-glx.so.0+0xb100]  xcb_glx_query_server_string_string_length+0x0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/LittleChild/workspace/jfx_practice/hs_err_pid10645.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I get this when I try to run my JavaFX program on 64bit Ubuntu 12.04.
Can someone tell me what it is ?

*There seems to be no answer to this on SO, I did check a similar question*

Comment: It could be a bug in the JDK, or it could be a bug in the `xcb-glx` library. It's impossible to know without running the JVM under a debugger.

Comment: I think the error spells it out pretty well - it's a potential bug in the JVM. You can submit a bug report using the link it provides. They'll want details on what you were doing when it failed, and perhaps the code you were running.

Comment: @Joni It was working fine yesterday .. I dunno what happened now

Comment: Did you update/install/uninstall some package? Searching the Internet for `xcb_glx_query_server_string_string_length` turns up bug reports related to video drivers. For example https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nux/+bug/958212